# Python - trying to replace a text string that contains ""

Tags: python

I have a problem which I cannot find an answer to:
I'm trying to replace a number inside a text string based on the user's input,  the text string looks like:
minRequiredPasswordLength="9", only the number inside quotemarks changes so I need to have .replace that accepts and changes any number present inside these quote marks (Regex??), but I have no clue how to do it as the number after = is in quote marks already.

I am trying to replace the number within "" with a r value provided by user.

```
with open('pass.config', 'r') as file:
    filedata = file.read()
r = input('What is the required Password Length?')
filedata = filedata.replace('minRequiredPasswordLength="any number"', 'minRequiredPasswordLength="value provided in r"')
with open('pass.config', 'w') as file:
    file.write(filedata)
```

So, if the user inputs 11 and minrequiredpasswordlength="9" it should change 9 to 11.

I will highly appreciate any help.

Comment: I suggest you either read/write your output data in a normal tabular/CSV type structure, or use a python structure (like pickle/JSON) (or use a database, probably overkill here)

Comment: So you've already guessed that a regex could do it, have you checked the documentation? Is there some part of it that is confusing?

Comment: @khelwood indentation fixed, thanks!

Comment: @Chris_Rands I'm still learning so it's still a bit of a dark magic, i will read about pickle/Jason, thank you!

Comment: @MarkRansom Yes I did, however, I did not know how to properly add regex in a text string inside " ", thanks anyway

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you have already found out, regex can do the job pretty easily:

```
import re

filedata = 'minRequiredPasswordLength="9"'
r = '11'

result = re.sub(r'minRequiredPasswordLength="\d*"', r'minRequiredPasswordLength="{}"'.format(r), filedata)
print(result)

>>>> minRequiredPasswordLength="11"
```